# Coloring in kruskals algorithm

Tags: java, kruskals-algorithm

I am implementing Kruskals algorithm in Java and i cannot figure out what would be the best/smartest way to track visited vertexes. Should i color them or just set vertex property to visited or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am implementing Kruskals algorithm in Java and i cannot figure out what would be the best/smartest way to track visited vertexes. Should i color them or just set vertex property to visited or something like that?

Coloring them and setting them as visited are two different things. If you want to set the node as visited, either you use an array of flags (array of boolean):

```
boolean[] visited = new boolean[numNodes];
visited[currNodeIdx] = true;
```

If you have created a class for the nodes, just update the attribute:

```
class Node{
    private boolean visited;
    public void visited(boolean flag){
        visited = flag;
    }
}
//when updating the node
node.visited(true);
```

Your backend algorithm should not be relying on your presentation layer (e.g. color changes) but instead, if you want to visually display the visited nodes, you can set the color according to the node's visited state (and not the other way round).

Comment: At the moment my code sets random color for each vertex. Then assigns random weight to each arc. I sort all arcs into array by weight and then start coloring visited vertexes in same color, moving from lower cost arcs. Judging by what you wrote i am doing it wrong or over complicating things? There is no other visual display as simple text output of a tree and then found minimum spanning tree using Kruskals algo.

Comment: If there is no visual presentation, what part does the color play in the algorithm?